# A better way to execute PDO statments

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am currently updating my database this way

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database;charset=utf8', 'username', 'password');
$updo = $db->prepare("UPDATE table SET weight = :weight WHERE height = 28");
$updo->execute(array(':weight' => $weight));
```

Is this the correct procedure. Are there any suggestions for improvement? In the PHP manual they wrote prepare statement like this

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare($sql, array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_FWDONLY));
```

This extra array confused me. I am using PDO first time so wanted to clear things up.

Comment: @Bob Thanx. Is it good to go other than that?

Comment: This question seems to be a better fit for http://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method will work, but defaults to escaping the bound params as strings. I think that best practice would be using [bindParam](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php) to specify that `$weight` should be an integer as below:

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database;charset=utf8', 'username', 'password');
$updo = $db->prepare("UPDATE table SET weight = :weight WHERE height = 28");
$updo->bindParam(':weight', $weight, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$updo->execute();
```